Find the sum of all six digit numbers formed by 12345789.
The question is to find the sum of all $6$ digit numbers formed by $1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9$, with A) repetition not allowed B)  repetition allowed:

It is very easy to find how many $6$ digit numbers formed, but how can someone find their sum that too I closed form, I just can't think of any approach.
Can anyone help with this ?.
It would be great if u can provide a general formula ( if any ) for such questions.


Hint :  each digit is equally likely to be represented in a given position.

Oh yeah, that's a good approach, but if 0 is included in the set of numbers?

Well, it isn't in your list, so no.

Try a simpler case. How many $2$ digit numbers can you make from $1,2,3$? They are $12, 13, 21, 31, 23, 32$. You know you have $3P2=6$ numbers to make. If you were to total them, in the units you'd get $1+1+2+2+3+3$ and in the tens you'd get $1+1+2+2+3+3$. Similarly for $2$ digit numbers from $1,2,3,4$ you would get $4P2=12$ numbers and adding them gives $1+1+1+2+2+2+3+3+3+4+4+4=3(1+2+3+4)$ in the units and the same in the tens. Can you see the pattern?

It is not of much value to give you "a formula for such questions". It is unlikely that you will encounter another exercise that's solvable by the formula applicable to this exercise. The point is not to know and apply a formula, it is to find a suitable formula. The suitable formula will be different for different questions.

Because the first answerer missed it: The set of allowed digits does NOT include 6.

@LEELACHOUDHARY, did you intend to skip 6 in the list of allowed digits?

As I said in the comments, giving a "general formula" won't be of much use to you. It won't apply to other exercises. The point must be to understand how to find the formula.
Anyway, consider this: If we have a list of all allowed combinations, like so:
$$123457\\
123458\\
123459\\
\dots$$
Then note that to obtain their sum, we could first calculate the sum of all the ones, the sum of all the tens, the sum of all the hundreds, etc., and then add those. That is:
$$1\cdot\textrm{sum of all digits in first place}\\
+10\cdot\textrm{sum of all digits in second place}\\
+\dots\\
+10^6\cdot\textrm{sum of all digits in sixth place},\\$$
where the sixth summand is skipped because 6 is not an allowed digits.
Due to the symmetry of the problem, the sum of all digits in $n$-th place is always the same, so this reduces to:
$$111111\cdot\textrm{sum of all digits in any given place}$$
So we need to find the sum of all digits in just one place. Let's say the first place. How many combinations are there for which the first digit is 1? As many as there are ways to choose 5 distinct digits among the 7 remaining digits, that is, $\frac{7!}{(7-5)!}$. There is the same number of combinations for which the first digit is 2, 3, 4, or any other number (except 6). So we have $\frac{7!}{(7-5)!}$ ones, twos, threes, etc., so the sum is:
$$\begin{align}&~~1\cdot\frac{7!}{(7-5)!}\\
&+2\cdot\frac{7!}{(7-5)!}\\
&+\dots\\
&+9\cdot\frac{7!}{(7-5)!}\\
=&(1+2+3+4+5+7+8+9)\cdot\frac{7!}{(7-5)!}\\
=&39\cdot\frac{7!}{(7-5)!}\end{align}$$
So the total sum is:
$$111111\cdot39\cdot\frac{7!}{(7-5)!}.$$
This is for forbidden repeat digits. If repeat digits are allowed, replace $\frac{7!}{(7-5)!}$ by $8^5$, since that's the number of five digit combinations with 8 digits to choose from.

Here is a completely different approach to my other answer. You say it is easy to find the total number of combinations with 6 digits. Let's call that number $A_6$. (For reference, $A_n=\frac{8!}{(8-n)!}$ for $n$ non-repeating digits or $A_n=8^n$ for $n$ possibly repeating digits).
Then due to the symmetry of the problem, every possible number appears equally often at each position. That is, at each position there are $\frac{A_6}{8}$ ones, just as many twos, threes, etc., that is, the sum of all numbers that appear at a certain position is
$$\begin{align}&\frac{A_6}{8}\cdot1+\dots+\frac{A_6}{8}\cdot9\\
=&\frac{A_6}{8}\cdot(1+2+3+4+5+7+8+9)\\
=&\frac{A_6}{8}\cdot39.\end{align}$$
As in my other answer, multiply by 111111 to obtain the total sum:
$$\frac{39\cdot111111A_6}{8}.$$

I thought that my two answers are different enough to warrant separate answers. If this is against some site rule, just tell me and I'll be happy to merge the answers.

@user2661923 Thanks for the heads up. Both answers are now corrected.
